# Multiple unique random number generation ms-access

Tags: sql, ms-access, random, unique

I want to generate X number of unique random numbers in a range and insert those numbers into a new table
The number of samples "X" will be defined when entered into a field of a table.

at the moment I have

`SELECT Int((End_Sample_No-Start_Sample_No)*Rnd()+Start_Sample_No) AS RandNum`

I am stuck on working out how to making more than 1 random number and ensuring that if I do make more than one it is not already used.

Any suggestion or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Access caches results for function calls for improved efficiency. Since `Rnd` is called with the same arguments, it will only be called once, and keeps returning the same result.

To avoid this, pass an argument. `Rnd` will take positive integers, and this won't affect what's returned.

```
SELECT Int((End_Sample_No-Start_Sample_No)*Rnd(ID)+Start_Sample_No) AS RandNum
```

Where `ID` is your autonumber column or another numeric column that's unique for every record.

Comment: Thanks, I release that further clarification is required.  I want X random numbers in the range specified. (upperbound-lowerbound)

Comment: if I was to put  in '10' value in place of ID are you saying I should get 10 random numbers? Because I am still only getting 1 result.

Comment: Nope,. you need to have a table with 10 different IDs. If you want to run this without a table, you can use the built-in `MSysObjects` as the table, and limit the amount of results by specifying `TOP 10`

Answer (score 1):

First, the no-code solution is set the field as *AutoNumber* and its property to *Random*.

Then, a (pseudo) random number will be inserted whenever a record is added, and you don't have to create the records in advance.

If than doesn't fit your purpose, it might be easier to apply the random numbers *after* the data have been inserted. Then you could use my function:

```vb
' Builds random row numbers in a select, append, or create query
' with the option of a initial automatic reset.
'
' 2018-09-11. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RandomRowNumber( _
    ByVal Key As String, _
    Optional Reset As Boolean) _
    As Single

    ' Error codes.
    ' This key is already associated with an element of this collection.
    Const KeyIsInUse        As Long = 457
   
    Static Keys             As New Collection
 
    On Error GoTo Err_RandomRowNumber
   
    If Reset = True Then
        Set Keys = Nothing
    Else
        Keys.Add Rnd(-Timer * Keys.Count), Key
    End If
   
    RandomRowNumber = Keys(Key)
   
Exit_RandomRowNumber:
    Exit Function
   
Err_RandomRowNumber:
    Select Case Err
        Case KeyIsInUse
            ' Key is present.
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            ' Some other error.
            Resume Exit_RandomRowNumber
    End Select

End Function
```

and an example query (using a table from the *Northwind* sample database):

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    [Order ID],
    [Unit Price],
    RandomRowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RandowRow
FROM
    [Order Details]
ORDER BY
    RandomRowNumber(CStr([ID]));
```

It is taken from my project [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers).

If you wish not pseudo-random numbers but *truly random numbers*, study my project [VBA.Random](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Random).

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way, but this works.

1. Create a temporary table with the records you want to assign random numbers to.
   The query will be different from case to case. If I understand you correctly, you only want the right number of records, and can just select an arbitrary field. In my example, I needed to use the query random1 to group records first since I am making  a random distribution of plant varieties across a field, but want plots with the same variety placed together. ORDER BY is not needed, but it makes it easier to see that the order changes the way you want in subsequent steps.

```
SELECT random1.Ans INTO Tmp_Randomisering
FROM random1
ORDER BY random1.Ans;
```

2. Assign an ID field to the table

```
ALTER TABLE  [Tmp_Randomisering] ADD COLUMN ID COUNTER;
```

3. Create a second temporary table by selecting all records from the first temporary table and sorting them in a random order based on their ID. The old ID field can be included for checking that the process worked in the intended way.

```
SELECT Tmp_Randomisering.Ans, CLng([tmp_randomisering].[ID]) AS old_ID INTO tmp_randomisering2
FROM Tmp_Randomisering
ORDER BY Rnd([tmp_randomisering].[ID]);
```

4.Add an ID column to get integers between 1 and the number of records in the random order.

```
ALTER TABLE  [Tmp_Randomisering2] ADD COLUMN ID COUNTER;
```

A macro will execute all steps quite quickly.
If you have very many records, and/or are running the queries very often, the repeated adding and deleting of records may cause bloating of the database file.